# remove_empty_bins does not work with elasticX in crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a problem with a scatter chart in dc.js using crossfilter.js. Actually my problem is double. When I use the function:

```
  function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
      return {
          all: function () {
              return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                  //return Math.abs(d.value) > 0.00001; // if using floating-point numbers
                  return d.value !== 0; // if integers only
              });
          }
      };
  };
```

The elasticX(true) and elasticY(true) work but the "unfiltered" data still display on my scatterChart. When i use the same function with return true; instead of return d.value !== 0;  the "unfiltered" data disappear but neither elasticX nor elasticY work...

Any idea to fix it ?

Moreover, my bubbleChart does not react to this changement. The x-Axis doesn't uses the elasticX parameter... The range always stays with the global Minimum and Maximum of all the datas...

Thanks a lot !!

My scatterChart:

```
 var dim1 = ndx1.dimension(function (d) {return [+d.OperatingCluster,+d.FreqErrorCluster] ;});
 var group1 = dim1.group();
 clusterOutsidescatterPlot
 //.width(300)
     .height(rowHeight)
     .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 2000]))
     .y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]))
     .yAxisLabel("Nombre d'occurences de l'erreur")
     .xAxisLabel("Apparition dans le cluster (secondes)")
     .yAxisPadding('5%')
     .xAxisPadding('5%')
     .transitionDuration(0)
    // .clipPadding(100)
    .dimension(dim1)
    .group(remove_empty_bins(group1))
      .elasticX(true)
      .elasticY(true)
      .brushOn(false)
     .excludedOpacity(0.5)
     .on("postRender", function(chart){
            chart.select("svg")
                .attr("viewBox", rowViewBoxAttr)
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin")
                .attr("width", "100%")
                .attr("height", "100%");
            chart.redraw();
  });
```

Comment: I know there are some issues with the way the scatterplot keys work: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/621 However I'm at a loss to explain the behavior you're seeing. If you're able to post a fiddle I'd be happy to take a look.